# How can I throw a sql query into the Viewbag

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I have 2 tables in my database. I want to compare and list the news items in table A that are not in table B.

**I wrote a sql query.**

```
SELECT ID FROM News_TB

where ID not in ( select News_ID From Slider_TB)
```

I need a Viewbag that uses this query to do the listing.On account controller.

**MY View Code in Account Controller**

```
public ActionResult SliderCategoryDetay(int ID)
        {
            var kontrol = _udb.SliderCategoryTB_Select().Where(m => m.SliderCategoryID == ID).First();
            ViewData["ID"] = kontrol.SliderCategoryID;

            ViewBag.slider = _udb.SliderTB_Select().Where(m => m.SliderID == ID);
            ViewBag.sliderhabercek = _udb.NewsTB_Select();    /*THİS*/
            return View();

        }
```

I want to do it on this page.Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you can use viewbag.data like this

```
public ActionResult SliderCategoryDetay(int ID)
        {
            var kontrol = _udb.SliderCategoryTB_Select().Where(m => m.SliderCategoryID == ID).First();
            ViewData["ID"] = kontrol.SliderCategoryID;

            ViewBag.data = kontrol;
            ViewBag.slider = _udb.SliderTB_Select().Where(m => m.SliderID == ID);
            ViewBag.sliderhabercek = _udb.NewsTB_Select();    /*THİS*/
            return View();

        }
```

And in your view use following example

```
@foreach(var item in ViewBag.data)
{
    @item.Value
}
```